# How to get list of most popular courses in moodle

Tags: moodle

Is there any way of showing list of most popular course and categories in moodle. Is there any inbuilt Plugin for it or it can only be done by writing custom piece of code .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you define most popular? There is the number enrolled which is probably the most useful way to define most popular.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS enrolments, c.id, c.fullname
FROM mdl_course c
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT e.courseid, ue.id AS userid
      FROM mdl_user_enrolments ue
      JOIN mdl_enrol e ON e.id = ue.enrolid) ue ON ue.courseid = c.id
GROUP BY c.id, c.fullname
ORDER BY 1 DESC, c.fullname
```

Update:

Use this inside Moodle

```
$sql = "SELECT c.id, c.fullname, COUNT(*) AS enrolments
        FROM mdl_course c
        JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT e.courseid, ue.id AS userid
              FROM {user_enrolments} ue
              JOIN {enrol} e ON e.id = ue.enrolid) ue ON ue.courseid = c.id
        GROUP BY c.id, c.fullname
        ORDER BY 3 DESC, c.fullname";
$course = $DB->get_record_sql($sql, array(), IGNORE_MULTIPLE);

echo $course->fullname;
```

Comment: In which table would i find the field number enrolled?

Comment: In the query above, enrolments is a count of enrolled users.

Comment: It shows the name of all courses that too in random order, not according to the number of enrollments.

Comment: I've updated the answer, so it can be used in moodle and will display the top course in the list. It doesn't account for multiple courses with the same number of enrolments though.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It worked. Do i need to write something else instead of IGNORE_MULTIPLE if i need the names of top 2 most popular courses?

Comment: Yeah use this instead `$courses = $DB->get_records_sql($sql, array(), 1, 2);` - see https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Data_manipulation_API

Comment: Thanks again and that link is really useful.

Comment: Hie, i need to find most popular categories too should i join the mdl_course_categories on mdl_user_enrolments and mdl_enrol.